# Calculated Field not populating - Pivot Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, calculated-field

Could someone give a short tip why the calculated.field is not being created ? the two sums show up but no the third.

```
'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ForwinPivotTable").PivotFields("Gross Profit (EUR)")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "GP (Eur) "
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ForwinPivotTable").PivotFields("Export Chargeable Weight (kg)")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
.Name = "Total Charg. Weight "
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ForwinPivotTable").CalculatedFields
.Add "GP/kg (Eur)", "= 'GP (Eur) '/ 'Total Charg. Weight '"
.PivotFields("GP/kg (Eur)").Orientation = xlDataField
End With
```

Comment: I'd assume  you've stuck an `On Error Resume Next` in your code. The `CalculatedFields` collection doesn't have a `PivotFields` property - that belongs to the `Pivottable` object. Move the `.CalculatedFields` bit to the next line.

Comment: Never use a range *object* as the `SourceData` argument - always use the address in R1C1 format including the sheet name - for example: `SourceData:="'" & PRange.worksheet.Name & "'!" & PRange.address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ForwinPivotTable")
    .CalculatedFields.Add "GP/kg (Eur)", "= 'Gross Profit (EUR)'/ 'Export Chargeable Weight (kg)'"
    .PivotFields("GP/kg (Eur)").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
```

Mistake I had made was referencing the fields not by source title but by title in the pivot table.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.